# Is there a way to make smaller epochs with Keras ImageDataGenerator and Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm training a CNN. I want to keep track the metrics in the shorter term, but I have way too many instances to wait for a complete epoch. Essentially, I want the `ImageDataGenerator` to select only a portion of the data to complete an epoch. Since I'm using Tensorflow, the epochs are run manually, so there is no `steps_per_epoch` argument.

Here is my data loading code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

path = 'my_path/'
os.chdir(path)

image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, validation_split=.2)

train_generator = image_generator.flow_from_directory(
    path,
    color_mode='grayscale',
    target_size=(30, 30),
    batch_size=16,
    classes=os.listdir(),
    subset='training')
```

And I'm running the epochs like this:

```
for epoch in range(5):
    for data, labels in train_generator:
        train_step(data, labels)

    for test_data, test_labels in validation_generator:
        test_step(test_data, test_labels)

    train_los.reset_states()
    train_acc.reset_states()

    test_los.reset_states()
    test_acc.reset_states()
```

`test_step()` is basically just running the data through the model and updating gradients.

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION:** Set `validation_split` to 0.9, so I have only 10% of the data, but that seems silly. Furthermore, if it keeps reusing the same 10% I'll be losing a lot of information.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that there going to be something prettier than simply:

```
EVALUATE_EVERY = 1000

def evaluate(step, generator, test_los, test_acc):
    for test_data, test_labels in generator:
        step(test_data, test_labels)
    test_los.reset_states()
    test_acc.reset_states()


for epoch in range(5):
    for i, (data, labels) in enumerate(train_generator):
        train_step(data, labels)
        if i % EVALUATE_EVERY == 0:
            evaluate(test_step, test_generator, test_los, test_acc)

    train_los.reset_states()
    train_acc.reset_states()
```

But I am no keras epxert.